# Getting stale values on using ifelse in a dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

Hi I am aggregating values from two columns and creating a final third column, based on priorities. If values in column 1 are missing or are NA then I go for column 2.

```
df=data.frame(internal=c(1,5,"",6,"NA"),external=c("",6,8,9,10))

df
      internal external
1        1         
2        5        6
3                 8
4        6        9
5       NA       10

df$final <- df$internal
df$final <- ifelse((df$final=="" | df$final=="NA"),df$external,df$final)

df
      internal external  final
1        1                2
2        5        6       3 
3                 8       4
4        6        9       4
5       NA       10       2
```

How can I get final value as 4 and 2 for row 3 and row 5 when the external is 8 and 2. I don't know what's wrong but these values don't make any sense to me.

Comment: You seem to be using mixed variable types within columns of the data frame (1 and 5 are numeric, but "" and "NA" are character). Vectors in R (a data frame is a list of vectors) need to be of a single type. So what is happening is that your columns are being cast into character types throughout, and probably then as factors (use dput to confirm that this is the case). If you cast your columns to numeric or integer using as.numeric or as.integer then things should go more smoothly

Answer (score 2):

The issue arises because R converts your values to factors.

Your code will work fine with

```
df=data.frame(internal=c(1,5,"",6,"NA"),external=c("",6,8,9,10),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

PS: this hideous conversion to factors  should definitely belong to the R Inferno, http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: Completely agree that this "hideous" conversion should be added to the inferno. Should probably also be noted there that this default behaviour can be changed by options("stringsAsFactors"=F). Putting this command into .Rprofile changes the default for your session. Of course, relying on this has its own pitfalls as code written using this default may break when run by another user or in another session.